# Как написать что функция равна нулю?

Tags: visual-c++, c#-8.0

[image: код на с++(с лева) нужно переписать на с#]

на картинке код на с++(с лева), а нужно переписать на с#

переписываю что у меня написано в коде:

```
 public virtual kyzov CreateKuzov()
    {
        return "0";
    }
    public virtual dvizh CreateDvygun()
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Это - не возврат значения, а то, что это - чисто виртуальная функция, делающая класс абстрактным. К сожалению, С# я не знаю, но подозреваю, что ближайший аналог - интерфейс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Компилятор C# не может преобразовать строку или число в kyzov/dvizh.

Попробуйте вернуть null.
Соответственно, далее в коде нужно скорректировать условия проверки, если таковые имеются.
Также можно добавить неявный оператор преобразования в kyzov и dvizh.

Comment: Это не о том...

Comment: Нет, это как раз таки и решило проблему